# How to get one column based on the other column when inserting into a table's column from other tables?

Tags: sql

I know it may be a little difficult to understand what I am saying.
You will get it soon:

    `CREATE TABLE user_used_total 
    (
        user varchar(10),
        used int,
        total int
    );`

```
INSERT INTO user_used_total 
VALUES ('A', 30, 100);

CREATE TABLE user_used_total_free_thenWhat 
(
    user varchar(10),
    used int,
    total int,
    free int,
    thenWhat varchar(10)
);
```

I am trying to do like this:

    `INSERT INTO user_used_total_free_thenWhat
    SELECT u.user, u.used, u.total, u.total - u.used, 
    CASE WHEN u.total - u.used > 50 THEN 'higher than 50' ELSE 'lower than 50' END 
    FROM user_used_total AS u;`

Is there any other way to replace `u.total - u.used` in `case WHEN u.total - u.used > 50 THEN 'higher than 50' ELSE 'lower than 50' END` based its front `u.total - u.used`?

I really need your help.

Comment: first: Please, state which flavor of SQL are you preferring the answer for? Second: proper syntax is. `Case when column1>123 then 'something' else 'something' end`

Comment: SQL 92. The column1 you mentioned is actually the free column of the user_used_total_free_thenWhat which is going to be inserted meanwhile.

Comment: add `When`  after the `case`...?

Comment: Sorry for my missing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking how to write `u.total - u.used` only once.
If that is the case then the bad news is that you can't use the computed value from the select list in the same select list, but the good news is that if your database supports common table expressions you can use a cte like this (This is t-sql syntax, not sure about other databases - you might need to change it a little):

```
;with cte as
(
    SELECT u.user, 
           u.used, 
           u.total, 
           u.total - u.used As free 
    FROM user_used_total
)

INSERT INTO user_used_total_free_thenWhat 
(
    user,
    used,
    total,
    free,
    thenWhat
)

SELECT user,
       used,
       total,
       free,
       CASE WHEN free > 50 THEN 
           'higher than 50' 
       ELSE 
           'lower than 50' 
       END 
FROM cte;
```

Comment: You got it. I just feel we can get another reflection of column, here 'thenWhat' based on the column,  'free' that needs other tables' information directory with only one sql command.Thanks for your help.I am to test it.

Comment: No `FROM` needed in the cte?

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for catching my typo :-)